# Proving limit of a sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

I need to prove the following:

$$\lim_{s \to \infty} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^s} = 1$$

This is my attempt:

\begin{align}
\lim_{s \to \infty} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^s} & =  \lim_{s \to \infty} \left( 1 + \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac 1 {n^s} \right) \\
& = 1 + \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \lim_{s \to \infty} \frac 1 {n^s} \\
& =  1 + \sum_{n = 2}^\infty 0 \\
& = 1
\end{align}

I need help justifying the interchange of the sum and the limit though. Is it enough to show the limit exists and the sum is convergent? I read that I need to prove uniform convergence, how can I do this?

Comment: Hint : Consider $\int \frac{1}{x^s}\ dx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s\gt 1$, and let our sum be $A(s)$. A picture shows that
$$1\lt A(s)\lt 1+\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^s}\,dx.$$
But $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^s}\,dx$ can be explicitly computed, and approaches $0$ as $s\to\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

For $s\ge 2$ we have
$$\frac1{n^s}\le \frac1{n^2}$$
and the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}$$
is convergent and doesn't depend on $s$ so the given series is uniformly convergent and you can interchange limit and sum.